# iPhone Static Code Analyzer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-analysis

A developing consensus among the iPhone developer community is that Apple has recently started using a static code analysis tool to detect use of undocumented API calls.

Just for the sake of the argument, I wonder if it would be possible to work around this tool by generating the invocation at runtime like this:

```
NSString *const aMethod = @"doStuff:withStuff:";
SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(aMethod);
NSMethodSignature *aSignature = [targetObject methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
NSInvokation *anInvokation = [NSInvokation invocationWithMethodSignature:aSignature];
[anInvokation setTarget:targetObject];
[anInvokation setSelector:aSelector];
[anInvokation setArgument:&firstArg atIndex:2];
[anInvokation setArgument:&secondArg atIndex:3];
[anInvokation invoke];
```

This almost seems too easy, so I wonder - what am I missing? How can Apple possibly detect this using static code analysis on the assembly?

A couple of points:

1. I am aware that the method name will
   be stored in the binary as a static
   string. It would however be trivial
   to generate the method name at
   runtime as well using
   stringWithFormat: or other type of
   slight obfuscation (enough to
   confuse the static analyzer).
2. I know that this trick would be revealed by even the most trivial runtime analysis using gdb - my understanding has been that Apple analyses the binary itself, and maybe I'm completely wrong about that.

Comment: The iPhone SDK and developer tools are licensed to you under a contract.  If you don't like the terms of that contract, then you should be targeting a platform where quality control isn't taken seriously.

Apple's got their reasons for rejecting apps that use undocumented methods (these are not API, by definition).  If you get cute and try to do an end-run like this, they could just drop you from the iPhone developer program, and they'd be right to do so.

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to say that I never meant to use Stack Overflow as a platform for voicing my opinion on the use of private API! If I wanted to do that I would've gone on Slashdot or developer forums.

I cannot understand why people take issue with asking an honest question out of interest in the matter and wanting to learn something, or why some seem to be of the opinion that some arbitrarily chosen topics should suddenly be taboo and forbidden to talk about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why care? You're not supposed to use private API for a good reason: Apple could easily break your application at any time, upsetting your users.

That said, use of NSInvocation, -performSelector: or any other similar technique is probably enough to avoid detection by a static analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you've read [this article](http://blog.roguesheep.com/2009/11/19/warning-love-hurts/). Also interesting is [this one](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/11/26/dear-aunt-tuaw-my-private-apis-arent/). My interpretation is that Apple's static analyzer does generate false positives just because some people use methods that have the same name as private methods. This would not have happened if the analyzer had done either a runtime analysis or thorough checking of which classes' selector has been called. So, it seems like they mainly are looking for matching strings or selectors in your binary. I think that using `NSInvocation` combined with some string obfuscation will get you through. I'd still recommend to not rely on private APIs, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way to find out!

Make an app that deliberately uses a hidden api through the method in your question and see it if gets accepted!

Sam

PS If you do find out, make sure you tell us; we'd all like to know for sure and Apple surely won't tell us!